# Can Matlab generate Java Source Code?

Tags: java, matlab

MATLAB provides toolboxes (Matlab Coder, Matlab compiler, Simulink Coder) to generate C and C++ source codes for built in function. I am wondering if there is any toolbox or feature to generate java source code ( not encrypted JAR / class files) for the matlab code/built in functions?

Comment: *"not encrypted JAR / class files"* They are encoded as binaries, rather than encrypted (by default).

Answer (score 11):

There is nothing that will convert MATLAB source code into Java source code. The add-on product MATLAB Builder JA will archive and encrypt your MATLAB source code, and create a standalone .jar file wrapper that enables you to call the MATLAB code from Java, but it doesn't produce Java source code.

Note that MATLAB Coder and Simulink Coder produce C, not C++ code, and that MATLAB Compiler works in a similar way to Builder JA, archiving and encrypting your MATLAB code and producing an executable wrapper.

**Edit**: since release R2015b, functionality to produce .jar files has been moved from MATLAB Builder JA to the new product MATLAB Compiler SDK, which will also produce .dll files and .NET assemblies. MATLAB Builder JA no longer exists as a product.

Comment: Simulink Coder can generate C++ [link](http://www.mathworks.com/products/simulink-coder/description1.html)

Comment: @pmb If you want to use a C++ compiler, you can tell that to MATLAB or Simulink Coder, and it will produce a `.cpp` file with C++ code to wrap its C code. But it does not really produce proper C++ code that, for example, uses classes. It's really producing C code.

Comment: true, it's not OO C++, but C++ nevertheless. I just thought it might be good to add that since someone might think they can't use Simulink Coder because of that...

Answer (score 5):

I think that is the product you are looking for: [MATLAB Builder JA](http://www.mathworks.com/products/javabuilder/) (but the builder encrypts your MATLAB functions and generates a Java wrapper around them so that they behave just like any other Java class.)

Comment: I think that runs inside of a runtime, so there is overhead for it.  An alternative is matlab coder which generates C code you can call using JNI.